# Woocommerce change basket icon to tick when product in the basket

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I added some code to my Wordpress site to change the basket icon to a tick/check a couple of years ago.  It worked perfectly.  Recently I was getting a critical error on my site and narrowed it down to this code.  I suspect that there have been subsequent changes in Woocomerce.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_cart() on null in /home/modjargo/public_html/wp-content/themes/ModjajiBooks/functions.php:159 Stack trace: #0 /home/modjargo/public_html/wp-content/themes/ModjajiBooks/functions.php(169): change_button_text(237520, '') #1 /home/modjargo/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): change_ajax_add_to_cart_button_text('', Object(WC_Product_Simple)) #2 /home/modjargo/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(191): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #3 /home/modjargo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-product-simple.php(62): apply_filters('woocommerce_pro...', 'Add to basket', Object(WC_Product_Simple)) #4 /home/modjargo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/loop/add-to-cart.php(32): WC_Product_Simple->add_to_cart_text() #5 /home/modjargo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php(345): include('/home/modjargo/...') #6 /home/modjargo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/in in /home/modjargo/public_html/wp-content/themes/ModjajiBooks/functions.php on line 159
> There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.

Could somebody help me to work out what might be wrong with this code?  The second line is the one mentioned in the error.

```
function change_button_text( $product_id, $button_text ) {
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        if( $product_id === $item['product_id'] ) {
            return __('&#x4e;', 'woocommerce');
        }
    }
    return $button_text;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'change_ajax_add_to_cart_button_text', 10, 2 );
function change_ajax_add_to_cart_button_text( $button_text, $product ) {
    if ( $product->is_type('simple') ) {
        $button_text = change_button_text( $product->get_id(), $button_text );
    }
    return $button_text;
}
```

Comment: What is the actual error message you get?

Comment: I've edited the post to show the error I was given.  It is in the second line of the code.

Comment: Where this error happened? Could you provide the sample url. My guess this happened in admin page.

Comment: Yes, this happened in the admin page, so I can't provide live URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WC()->cart` doesn't exist in admin hence the `get_cart() get called on null` error. You can add `!is_admin()` check so it will not execute in admin page.

```
function change_ajax_add_to_cart_button_text( $button_text, $product ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $product->is_type('simple') ) {
        $button_text = change_button_text( $product->get_id(), $button_text );
    }
    return $button_text;
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Appreciate if you could accept this as answer to your question so others can find this answer useful.

Comment: Done.  Sorry, I thought I'd accepted it but I just selected it as useful.  